# Python: Combining two different plots in one plot but different x value range

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, boxplot

I would like to combine a pointplot and a boxplot into one plot using seaborn. The combination itself works, but since the x-axis-values of both dataframes are not in the same range, I get a wrong output (x-values of second dataframe will be ignored).
Here are parts of my datasets:

```
import pandas as pd
bpdata=pd.DataFrame({'Ldate': [20150202, 20150202, 20150202, 20151117, 20151117, 20151117, 20160205, 20160205, 20160205], 'Lreflectance': [0.067, 0.0482, 0.0555, 0.099, 0.0956, 0.0931, 0.0757, 0.0663, 0.0566]})
Mplotdata=pd.DataFrame({'Mdate':[20150202, 20150407,20160202], 'Mreflectance': [0.0868, 0.0833,0.0719]})
```

Plottet individually:

```
import seaborn as sns
plot=sns.pointplot(data=Mplotdata, x='Mdate', y='Mreflectance', color='dimgrey', marker='o')
for item in plot.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(45)

plot=sns.boxplot(data=bpdata, x='Ldate', y='Lreflectance', color='lightgray')
for item in plot.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(45)
```

Looks like this:
[pointplot (left) and boxplot (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GaT9.jpg)

But when I try to put both pointplot and boxplot into one plot

```
plot=sns.boxplot(data=bpdata, x='Ldate', y='Lreflectance', color='lightgray')
plot=sns.pointplot(data=Mplotdata, x='Mdate', y='Mreflectance', color='dimgrey', marker='o')
for item in plot.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(45)
```

it looks like this: 
[image: combined plot]

In this plot, the x-axis only shows values of the first plot. If I change the order of pointplot and boxplot, it will also just use x-values of the first dataframe, second will be ignored.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

I haven't found any solution to this in this forum, google or in the matplotlib/seaborn documentations.

Comment: Could you include ([edit]) some minimal dataset that reproduces the problem? Please have a look at [mcve] when asking for debugging help.

Comment: Thanks @MSeifert, is done.

Comment: It's not clear which values you expect to see where in the plot. Also the images you show do not seem to match the data. Remember that the people you are talking to here may be experts in data analysis and plotting with python, but they have no clue about your special problem, so you need to explain it to them.

Comment: That's true, I'm sorry! The first picture consisted of two plots, a boxplot and a pointplot. Then it would be clear. I don't know, why just one is shown, i'll try to add the other. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twiny() # put a second plot on top of it, having the same y axis
data1 = np.random.random(10) #random in [0,1]
data2 = np.random.random(15)+1 #random in [1,2]

ax.plot(np.arange(len(data1)), data1) # plot in the first plot
ax2.plot(np.arange(len(data2)),data2) # plot in the second plot
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @JürgMerlinSpaak, that's it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twiny()
plot=sns.boxplot(data=bpdata, x='Ldate', y='Lreflectance', color='lightgray', ax=ax)
plot=sns.pointplot(data=Mplotdata, x='Mdate', y='Mreflectance', color='dimgrey', marker='o', ax=ax2)
for item in plot.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(45)
```

[image]

The size of the plot and the boxes still need to be improved, but the combination of both plots works fine. Thank you!